# Ubuntu Core 18 - RPI 3B+ Camera not detected

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, camera

Did anybody tried to make the raspberry pi camera work with Ubuntu Core 18 ?
Is it supposed to work ?

Whatever I'm trying gives me an error saying the camera is not detected.

mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component ‘vc.ril.camera’
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component

I'm 100% sure the camera is connected, because I quickly reinstalled raspbian and the camera works.

Thanks in advance.

Benjamin

Comment: Seems your question has already been answered on the Raspberry Pi stack exchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37359/how-to-use-raspistill-on-ubuntu#37387

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu Core 18, the camera is not detected: "vcgencmd get_camera" gives "supported=0 detected=0"

Comment: Have you performed every step of the answer?

Comment: Yes, I updated the boot config, I updated the firmware even though I'm not sure it's necessary, then I installed the userland just to be able to use vcgencmd and raspistill, but the camera is never detected. I tried multiple times, with and without a fresh installation. I tried every single how to I found on the internet. It's been 4 days now that I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Nope, I even retried recently, but no luck.